# Batch operations in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs, batch-processing, resteasy

**Context**

I am currently working on a JavaEE project with a lot of existing resource based JAX-RS services. For this project we would like to have batch processing to prevent a lot of separate calls and, most importantly, to execute these different methods in a transactional context for rollback purposes with the native MongoDB driver. We want to avoid manually creating new methods for all possible combinations. I could not find any solution to this issue on Stack Overflow so I started analyzing the implementation of RESTEasy and I came up with the following solution.

Below a simplified/pseudo version of my code:

JAX-RS method

```
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("execute")
    public Response executeBatch(BatchRequestWrapper batchRequestWrapper) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {       
        // Retrieve information from context
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpServletRequest.class);
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpServletResponse.class);
        ServletContext servletContext = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(ServletContext.class);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpResponse.class);
        SynchronousDispatcher dispatcher = (SynchronousDispatcher) ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(Dispatcher.class);
        ResteasyHttpHeaders httpHeaders = (ResteasyHttpHeaders) ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(HttpHeaders.class);
        ResteasyUriInfo uriInfo = (ResteasyUriInfo) ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(UriInfo.class);
        
        // Create Mongo Client Session object and save it in a Singleton which contains a ThreadLocal object so that DAO layer can reuse the client session object for all methods.


        // Iterate over all the methods and invoke dispatcher
        for (BatchRequest batchRequest : batchRequestWrapper.getBatchRequests())
        {
            // Update URI based on specific endpoint
            uriInfo.setRequestUri(URI.create(batchRequest.getUri()));

            // Temporary use mock response for the response
            MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

            // Create httpservletinput message from RESTEasy lib to pass to the dispatcher. It will automatically resolve all parameters/methods etc.
            HttpServletInputMessage request = new HttpServletInputMessage(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, servletContext, httpResponse, httpHeaders, uriInfo, batchRequest.getHttpMethod(), dispatcher);

            // Set body in input stream if body is specified. This will inject the correct 'body' parameters in the methods. Query and Path parameters are already resolved in the method above.
            if(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(batchRequest.getBody()))
            {
                InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(batchRequest.getBody().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                request.setInputStream(targetStream);
            }

            // Actual invoke
            dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

           // Do something with response object
        }

        // Clean or abort session based on invoke result

        return Response.ok().entity(null).build();
    }
```

Request Object

```
public class BatchRequestWrapper
{
    private List<BatchRequest> batchRequests;

    public List<BatchRequest> getBatchRequests()
    {
        return batchRequests;
    }

    public void setBatchRequests(List<BatchRequest> batchRequests)
    {
        this.batchRequests = batchRequests;
    }
}

public class BatchRequest
{
    private String uri;
    private String httpMethod;
    private String body;

    public String getUri()
    {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri)
    {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public String getHttpMethod()
    {
        return httpMethod;
    }

    public void setHttpMethod(String httpMethod)
    {
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    }

    public String getBody()
    {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body)
    {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

My solution works with one new REST method and let's me reuse all the existing JAX-RS annotated methods in the project. Before I actually fully implement this and bring it to production, I would like to know if this is the way to actually do this or are there better alternatives? I am not a big fan of the hard dependency on RESTEasy though.

Comment: I would highly suggest not making this so implementation specific. I also don't think you're going to get any better performance this way. You might want to look at using async operations. There are several ways to do that. You could use CDI to inject the MongoClient and share it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! The most important thing is executing these separate calls in batch to be able to rollback when one of the executions results in an exception. For example: 

batch 1
- start transaction
- call 1 -> create new object in collection A 
- call 2 -> update object in collection B
- call 3 -> exception
- rollback all calls

How would you do this with async operations? I can share the mongoclient but how to share clientsession(transaction) across async methods?

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm not too familiar with the MongoClient. I was just making a guess that it could be shared :) What container and version are you running in?